# How to display the label with "Identify Features" in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have been struggling for one hour with this simple problem (QGIS 1.8.0-Lisboa, Windows 7) :

I have a raster layer. I would like to display the label and not only the band value when I use the `Identify Features` button. Is it possible?

Comment: Would you like to create a lasting text label for selected grid cells in the raster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thinks its two different things..according to me you can get only band details..
You can not attach attribute data to raster file like Satellite image,topo-sheet etc.

So you will get only band details...