# QGIS - Is it possible to display a raster label (not band value) using identify tool or any other tool?

Tags: qgis, raster, labeling

This question [was asked 4 years ago](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37302/how-to-display-the-label-with-identify-features-in-qgis), but I hope that new QGIS features may have produced an anwswer.

In the new QGIS version, are there new raster features  similar to the vector features "action button", label menu or Qt Designer form, that may allow  to display a raster label (not band value) ?