# Can QGIS 3.0 identify tool give labels as well as band values for selected raster pixels

Tags: qgis, raster, identify

I'm using QGIS 3.0 for comparison of several landcover grids. These have a set style with 72 categories of landuse. The Style menu allows you to give a text label for each value within a band. The Identify tool gives the band and value for a particular pixel but does not give the label - which forces you to remember or look-up value labels.

Is there some setting to show the associated labels with the Identify results?

Comment: I see that a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37302/how-to-display-the-label-with-identify-features-in-qgis) was asked a few years ago for an earlier version of QGIS but it did not receive any good answers (you can associate labels with raster band values but they don't show up with identify). Is there perhaps an extension that addresses this?

Comment: Please note that it is not helpful for the discoverability of good answers to duplicate questions every couple of years. You can [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw attention to the original question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).